# Is it possible to set default options for pandoc?

Tags: pandoc

Is it at all possible to set default options for [pandoc](http://www.pandoc.org)? For example, I *always* want to use xelatex to generate PDFs, and as far as I can tell, my options for doing so are to pass `--latex-engine=xelatex` to *every* invocation of pandoc, or to write a wrapper script that just calls pandoc with that option.

Both of these seem suboptimal to me, and nearly every other command-line program has ways to get around this. Sometimes it's done with an environment variable in the shell (something like setting `PANDOC_OPTS="--latex-engine=xelatex"`), and other times it's a configuration file (ala `~/.gitconfig` or the like). I know pandoc has a data directory at `~/.pandoc`, but from my reading of the documentation there is no way to do this.

Comment: you can also set an `alias` in your `~/.bash_profile` or similar file...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since pandoc 2.8, one can provide default options via the [`--defaults` command line parameter](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--defaults):

> `-d` *FILE*, `--defaults=`*FILE*
>
> Specify a set of default option settings.  *FILE* is a YAML
>   file whose fields correspond to command-line option
>   settings.  All options for document conversion, including input
>   and output files, can be set using a defaults file.  The file will
>   be searched for first in the working directory, and then in
>   the `defaults` subdirectory of the user data directory
>   (see `--data-dir`).  The `.yaml` extension may be omitted.
>   See the section [Default files](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#default-files) for more information on the
>   file format.  Settings from the defaults file may be
>   overridden or extended by subsequent options on the command
>   line.

Comment: Oh wow, I'd forgotten I even wanted this. Thanks for digging this question up!

Comment: Can you actually set a... _default_ defaults file?

Comment: @detly no, but you can place a file, say `detly.yaml` in the `$USERDATA/defaults` directory, where `$USERDATA` is the folder reported by `pandoc -v` – you might have to create the folder first. With that in place you can run `pandoc -d detly`.

Comment: @tarleb yeah, I saw that in the docs. it doesn't help with tools that call pandoc themselves though. I was hoping to set up a default template and set of options.